# How can I fix < TypeError: paint() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'event' and 'window' >

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create a window, which can draw some circles. Using the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Canvas as c

window = Tk()
window.configure(background = "grey")
window.title("Canvas - Draw Shapes")

f_top = Frame(window)
f_bot = Frame(window)
f_top.pack()
f_bot.pack()

# elements
button_1 = Button(f_bot, text='Левая кнопка')
button_2 = Button(f_bot, text='Правая кнопка')
button_1.pack(side=LEFT)
button_2.pack(side=LEFT)

# setting up the canvas
canvas = Canvas(f_top, width=500, height=300, bg = "white")
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

def paint(event, window):
    x1, y1 = ( event.x - 4 ), ( event.y - 4 )
    x2, y2 = ( event.x + 4 ), ( event.y + 4 )
    window.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = black )

canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint())
window.mainloop()
```

This code returns

> TypeError: paint() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'event' and 'window'

I've tried to use `self` and 'event' and some others as the first argument and 'window', 'canvas' as the second.

Comment: By the way, I wanted to point out that your `import`s could be cleaned up to save you some trouble. Instead of `from tkinter import *`
`from tkinter import Tk`
`from tkinter import Canvas as c`, you should use the convention `import tkinter as tk`, then namespace your widgets accordingly: `window = tk.Tk()`, `canvas = tk.Canvas()`, etc. This practice will save you some headaches in the long run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your event binding is set up incorrectly.
It should be: `('<B1-Motion>', paint)` (note the lack of `()` after the function name). This should pass the `event` to `paint` automatically.

Also, you should be able to remove the `window` argument. What you want here is `canvas.create_oval`. You don't need a special argument for this since `canvas` is in the global scope.

And one last thing - you'll need quotes around the color string for `fill`.

```
def paint(event):
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 4), (event.y - 4)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 4), (event.y + 4)
    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='black')
```

Essentially what was happening is that when you wrote `canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint())`, you were calling `paint()` with 0 arguments, and (as originally written), it expected 2 arguments. By removing the parenthesis, you're no longer calling the function needlessly. Instead, you're assigning it as the callback for the event binding.

Comment: Thanks!! I can only add, that without argument 'window' it returned
> AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'create_oval'

I've solved this that way:

~~~
def paint(event, window=canvas):
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 4), (event.y - 4)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 4), (event.y + 4)
    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='black')
~~~

Comment: Could you also help me with editing my comments? I would like that function to be showed as code. '''code''', Ctrl+K and some other ways weren't working. Thanks a lot once more

Comment: I imagine you got that `AttributeError` originally when you were attempting to call `window.create_oval()` which doesn't exist. And if you're talking about formatting these comments, you can mark code by surrounding it with single backtick characters "`" the same way you would in the body of a question or answer. There's a `help` link that appears next to the text field as you're editing the comment that will explain formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint())
```

Because `paint()` has the parentheses, it is being called *right now*, which isn't what you want.

The purpose of `canvas.bind()` is to specify a function which will be called *later*, in response to some event.

So, the fix is probably to just pass the function *name*:

```
canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint)
```

And then internally, the `canvas.bind()` function saves a reference to that function, so it can be called later.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Saying "doesn't work" isn't much of a description.  Do you have an actual error message?

Comment: Look @JRiggles's answer. You got typo error. canvas.create_oval not window.create_oval

Comment: @toyotaSupra What?  My answer does not contain "window.create_oval" at all.  What error did I supposedly make?

Comment: @JohnGordon the original code in the question erroneously says `window.create_oval()`. You're still correct, but OP's code has more issues than just this. I think Supra is just "off by one" as it were